# Why new and delete operators signatures are different from all other operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

The signature for the new operator is:

```
void* operator new(size_t count)
```

There is a white space between the word "operator" and the word "new". This is:

1. Different from all other operator signatures (besides new, delete and their array counterparts). for example:

   `T& operator=(const T& other)`
2. Does not comply with function name rules of C++ which do not allow white spaces.

I assume that "operator" is a keyword in this case... But if this is correct, why isn't this the case in all other operator function signatures?

Is there an explanation for the inconsistency?

Comment: Note that it's not just `new` and `delete`, but conversion operators need the space as well.

Comment: You are working under a misunderstanding with regard to whitespace. There is absolutely nothing in the C++ language that requires there to be no space between `operator` definitions. `operator += (...)` is the same as `operator+=(...)` ([see an example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PPxvj4n1E)). The language grammar/syntax is only determined in terms of tokens, of which `operator` is a token that must precede the type of operator being defined (whether that's `new`, `+=`, `=`, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ grammar is actually written in terms of tokens, which *is* consistent between all types of operator definitions. `operator`s are special-purpose and fixed in terms of what tokens can follow after the `operator` keyword, but the whitespace that occurs is not mandated anywhere in the standard.

As far as the C++ grammar is concerned, there is no difference between the following signatures:

```cpp
auto operator+=(const Foo&) -> Foo&
auto operator +=(const Foo&) -> Foo&
auto operator += (const Foo&) -> Foo&
auto 
operator
+=
(const Foo&) -> Foo&
```

<kbd>[See example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9vMYohPvc)</kbd>

`operator new` is no more, or less, consistent here. The only deviation here is that some operators *allow* no space after the `operator` token, such as `operator=` -- and the reason for this is the way that tokens are broken up in the C++ grammar.

Most tokens are alphanumeric sequences that break on special characters, such as whitespace or `+`,`=`, etc. In this case, `operator=` breaks into two tokens -- `operator` and `=`, which form the operator.

This also follows that some operators are also compounds of multiple tokens, such as `operator new[]` -- which can also be written `operator new []`, since it is comprised of 3 tokens: `operator`, `new`, and `[]`, as evident in the footnote from [[over.oper.general]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper.general#1):

> [Note [1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper.general#note-1): The operators new[], delete[], (), and [] are formed from more than one token.
> The latter two operators are function call and subscripting.
> — end note]

Answer (score 5):

`void* operatornew(size_t count)` is a function named `operatornew` that takes a `size_t` and returns a `void*`.

The reason no space is needed in `operator=` and most other operators is that those symbols are not valid in a name, so `operator=` does not need the space.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I can use operator= instead of operator = (with a space) because there is no ambiguity whereas operatornew can be interpreted as a "normal" function?

Comment: @DM Yep.  The name can only be one thing with `operator=`.  `operatornew` could be a mistake or what you really wanted.